# Run python files at the same time subprocess

Tags: python

I have searched and tried a lot of codes for that topic. I am trying to run two python files but to run both at the same time
This is my try

```
import subprocess

subprocess.run("py pop1.py & py pop2.py", shell=True)
```

But this executes the first python then the second one. This is not the target. My target is to run both files at the same time.

Comment: What shell are you invoking? In Bash, the `&` puts the thing on the left into a background task, so the two actually do run simultaneously. But mileage may vary on other shells

Comment: Based on the use of the `py` command, I'm guessing you are on Windows.  The Windows command line does not support starting multiple commands at once.  They'll run serially.  You can simulate that by using multiple calls to `subprocess`.

Comment: Yes, I am using Windows. Is there any workaround to run the file at the same time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`subprocess` can do this all on its own without invoking `shell=True` with the `&` bashism.

```py
import subprocess

# start processes running in parallel
p1 = subprocess.Popen(['py', 'pop1.py'])
p2 = subprocess.Popen(['py', 'pop2.py'])

# wait for both processes to complete
p1.wait()
p2.wait()
```